# git cherry-pick but get exactly the same file structure

Tags: git

I have following case. I'm working on some files and made 
commits. E.g:

F -> G -> H (here I created and remomed many files) -> J -> K

I want to return to commit F but get exactly the same file structure
that was when this commit is performed. When I execute:

```
git cherry-pick <<commit F sha id>> --strategytheirs
```

I get exactly the same content in the files that exists when commit 
F is performed but I also want to have exactly the same file structure. If files were created I want them to not exists in result. 
Yes, I know that I can create branch from F and merge it but there must 
be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to checkout F and cherry-pick the new commits if necessary. If you do not require any of the commits(G, H, J, K), 
you can always run a hard reset on the same branch like this:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
```

This will remove all the commits created after F and delete all the files and restore it to exactly how it was when F was created.

Edit:

A third but complicated way to go about it is

1. hard reset your commits to H
2. do a soft reset to G. This will restore the files.
3. commit H again
4. cherry-pick J and K

Comment: Thank you for your response but I want to keep these commits.